# How can I combine multiple char's to make a string?

Tags: c++, string, char

I am doing string parsing and essentially what I would like to do is something like this:

```
string signature = char[index+1] + '/' + char[index+2];
```

BUT you can't do string concatenation on char's so that brings me to this question, how can I simulate concatenation on char's?

I know that the string library in C++ has append but I don't think that works for my case.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can concatenate chars to a `std::string`, you just need one of the operands to be a `std::string`, otherwise you are adding integers.

```
std::string signature = std::string() + char_array[index+1] + '/' + char_array[index+2];
```

Note that this only works if either the first or second operand in the chain is a `std::string`.  That will result in the first call to `operator+` returning a `std::string`, and the rest will follow suit.  So this doesn't give the expected results:

```
std::string signature = char_array[index+1] + '/' + char_array[index+2] + std::string();
```

Answer (score 15):

In C++11 you can actually do:

```
std::string signature{chars[index+1], '/', chars[index+2]};
```

Not sure how useful this will be in real code, but it deals with your example.

Comment: not only useful, but likely the most efficient version compared to the other answers. RAII

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Steve's and Benjamin's solution, you can also use a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << char_array[index + 1] << '/' << char_array[index + 2];
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate characters and C-style strings to an existing string rather easily:

```
string signature;

signature += char_array[index + 1];  // append character from char_array[index+1]
signature += '/';
signature += char_array[index + 2];  // append character from char_array[index+2]
```

You just need to ensure the left side of the `+` or `+=` is a `std::string`.